# When should I use scanf with the address of '&' ampersand key?

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I have to read in a text file with names and numbers. The names represent candidates in a dummy election (7 in total) and the numbers represent the voters. If the voter number is not in the range of the 7 candidates it gets thrown out but still stored. Finally, I have to print out the results of who won the election and how many spoilt votes there were.

This is my text file:

```
Robert Bloom 
John Brown 
Michelle Dawn 
Michael Hall 
Sean O’Rielly 
Arthur Smith 
Carl White 

3 8 1 3 1 6 12 9 6 5 0 2 8 4 
6 6 8 3 2 8 0 12 6 1 8 3 2 2 
3 2 5 7 4 11 8 6 11 12 11 7 5 5 
8 9 10 12 1 3 12 12 9 11 7 9 3 1 
2 10 12 7 11 9 6 6 0 1 10 7 11 2 
8   0 12 8 10 11 2 2 8 4 2 12 3 2 
9   1 4 8 8 7 7 4 12 2 10 10 9 4 
12 9 3 12 0 4 8 0 6 5 9 0 5 3 
11  6   0   3   0
```

This is where I am stuck about how to scan these in properly

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * data;
int spoilt=0;

typedef struct
{
 int votes;
 char name[20];
}candidates;

void initialize( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<7; i++ )
    {
        fscanf( data, "%[^\n]%*c", electionCandidates[i].name );
        printf( "%s\n", electionCandidates[i].name );
        electionCandidates[i].votes=0;
    }

}

int processVotes( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )
{
    int i;                                           //tallying votes
    int voter;
    for ( i = 0; i< 365; i++ )
    {
       fscanf( data, "%d", voter );
       if ( voter <= 7&& voter > 0 )
        electionCandidates[voter-1].votes++;
       else
        spoilt++;
    }

                                                    //catcher to grab winner
    int maxValue, winner=0;

    maxValue = electionCandidates[0].votes;
    for( i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        if( maxValue < electionCandidates[i].votes )
        {
            maxValue = electionCandidates[i].votes;
            electionCandidates[winner] = electionCandidates[i];
        }

    }

    return electionCandidates[winner], maxValue;


}

void printResults( candidates *electionCandidates )
{
    printf("%s won the election with a total of %d votes.\n There was a total of %d spoilt"
            electionCandidates[winner].name, maxValue, spoilt);

}


int main() {
    data = fopen( "elections.txt","r" );
    candidates electionCandidates[7];

    initialize( electionCandidates, data );
    processVotes( electionCandidates, data );
    printResults( electionCandidates );


    fclose( data );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it even compiling? What are you doing with this `return electionCandidates[winner], maxValue;`?? Are you trying to return 2 values?

Comment: This is where I think im messing up. I am trying to find the winner of the election and return the value of the position in the structure array

Comment: Just return the index of the winner. With that you can directly access the name and the number of votes from the array

Comment: `void initialize( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )` does not compile. Are you using a C++ compiler ?

Comment: @wildplasser: why wouldn't it compile? Compiles fine for me (using clang).

Comment: I rest ny case. I see you added a needless typedef to your struct definition. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `scanf`, you must provide the *address* of the variable that you want to scan the result into. Provide the address by using the `&` operator. Also, it is a good idea to check the result of `scanf` to ensure that it successfully scanned what you asked for. `scanf` will always return the number of elements successfully scanned, unless an I/O error occurred, in which case it will return a negative number.

Here's an fixed, annotated version of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
 int votes;
 char name[20];
}candidates;

// specify a new type to hold the election result data
typedef struct
{
  int winner;
  int maxVotes;
  int spoilt;
} electionResult;

void initialize( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<7; i++ )
    {
        fscanf( data, "%[^\n]%*c", electionCandidates[i].name );
        printf( "%s\n", electionCandidates[i].name );
        electionCandidates[i].votes=0;
    }

}

// This function can now return more than one value, because we've wrapped
// the relevant info into a structure called "electionResult"
electionResult processVotes( candidates *electionCandidates, FILE *data )
{
    // declare the election result struct here (which we fill with data)
    // we initially set all values to 0

    electionResult er = {0, 0, 0};
    int i;                                           //tallying votes
    int voter;
    for ( i = 0; i< 365; i++ )
    {
       // scan the vote by providing the address of voter (using &)
       int result = fscanf( data, "%d", &voter );
       if (result == 1)
       {
          if ( voter <= 7&& voter > 0 )
             electionCandidates[voter-1].votes++;
          else
             er.spoilt++;
       }
    }

    er.maxVotes = electionCandidates[0].votes;
    for( i = 0; i < 7; i++ )
    {
        if( er.maxVotes < electionCandidates[i].votes )
        {
            // update the values in the election result struct
            er.maxVotes = electionCandidates[i].votes;
            er.winner = i;
        }
    }

    return er;
}

// this function now prints the result of the election by accepting an "electionResult" struct
void printResults( candidates *electionCandidates, electionResult er )
{
    printf("%s won the election with a total of %d votes.\n There was a total of %d spoilt",
            electionCandidates[er.winner].name, er.maxVotes, er.spoilt);

}


int main() {
    FILE *data = fopen( "elections.txt","r" );
    candidates electionCandidates[7];
    electionResult er;

    initialize( electionCandidates, data );
    er = processVotes( electionCandidates, data );
    printResults( electionCandidates, er );


    fclose( data );
    return 0;
}
```

Some tips:

- You can't access variables declared in other functions. You must return the data you want from one function and provide it to the other function.
- Avoid having variables declared at file scope if you can. For simple programs like this, it isn't much of an issue, but in general, using global variables tends to get messy fast.
- You can't return more than one value from a function unless you wrap up the values in a struct, like the above, or alternatively, have your function accept *pointers* to the objects that will hold the result, similar to how `fscanf` accepts `&voter` and subsequently fills the `voter` variable with the appropriate data (if it can).

Comment: I cant get this to compile in Dev C++ even when I try using a getwhile loop like this:      
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

Comment: Desktop\mikehomework\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [theElection.o] Error 1

Comment: @user3498869: There must be a more descriptive error than that somewhere ... it compiles fine for me (I am using clang rather than dev-c++, but I enable all warnings and pedantic mode and still get no errors). Are you sure your source code matches the above?

Comment: Wow I'm coming back to my questions and some of them I'm embarrassed I asked.

Comment: @Fappycow Never feel embarrassed, instead just use it as a reference point for how much you've learned.